# Will shiny Pokemon appear when playing Pokemon Rumble on an emulator?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-rumble

I know there are shinies for Rumble on the Wii console but I've been playing it on PC as an emulator because I don't have my Wii anymore. So can shinies appear when playing Rumble in dolphin emulator? I have seen like 15,000 pokemon and still no shiny.

Or does dolphin emulator not contain shinies for Pokemon Rumble?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Dolphin Emulator Wiki](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Pok%C3%A9mon_Rumble), there are no reported problems with the title. And, according to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon#Pok.C3.A9mon_Rumble_series), a Pokémon wiki, "Shiny Pokémon may rarely appear. They will always tip over when defeated. The chances of their appearance are unconfirmed, although they appear to occur more often than in the core series."

This seems to just be a case of really bad luck in your case. Unless your copy of the game is faulty, shinies should still appear, as Dolphin Emulator does not adjust any properties of your game.